# PHP. Excel not showing correctly.

Tags: php, excel

I have this simple code

```
<?php
//header info for browser
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
echo pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf);//utf-8
/* * *****Start of Formatting for Excel****** */

$data = "text1 \t text2 \t";

print($data);
?>
```

That creates an excel file. My problem is that the \t tab character is not working. Everything is in the first column of the excel file. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you looked into PHPExcel?

Comment: Just figured out that this line echo pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf); makes the problem. I may need something else for utf-8

Comment: Please not that this isn't actually an Excel .xls file that you're creating; it's a csv file (with a tab separator). Some versions of MS Excel will display a warning when opening this, although they will normally open it successfully (in most cases, locale variants apply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, I found a solution

```
  <?php
  //header info for browser
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");
  header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Expires: 0");

  $data = "text1 \t text2 \t";
  $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
  $data = "\xFF\xFE" . $data;

  echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm use "\r\n" escs not so long:

```
$data = "text1 \\t text2 \\t";
echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($data); 
echo '</pre>';
```